# CSS layout fixed bottom, variable height

Tags: css

this is the problem that I have been struggling with:

[image: the example]

So, I have this right bar with three sections ("Arhiva", "Naznake" and "Svi članci"). The first and second one have static positioning and have variable height (based on the data). The second one does have a maximum height.
The third one gives me problems. I want to fix it's bottom to the bottom of the right bar, and the top to the bottom of the "Naznake" (the second section). So far it has only two small boxes inside, but as soon as I will the database it will overflow beneat the right bar.
Here is the problem:
 - if I use height:100% - it will still overflow underneat for the height of the first two elements.
 - if I use calc(height:100% - some falue) it would solve this problem, but as soon as either first or second section change their height, it will again stop working the way it should.

So, this is my dillema - how to fix bottom of the lowest section to the bottom of its parrent div, and the top to the bottom of the preceeding sibbling div and still be able to scroll it when it is larger than the available area?

Here is my relevant HTML:

```
<div id="articlebar">
    <h1><?php echo lang('ARCHIVE_TITLE');?></h1>
    <section id="archiveSpace"><?php echo $godine->prepare_years($db); ?><div style="clear:both"></div></section>
    <h1><?php echo lang('TAGS');?></h1>
    <section id="tagSpace"><?php echo $tagovi->prepare_tags($db); ?><div style="clear:both"></section>
    <h1><?php echo lang('ALL_ARTICLES');?></h1>
    <section id="artList"><?php echo $others->prepare_others($db); ?><div style="clear:both"></section>
</div>
```

Here is my relevant CSS:

```
#articlebar {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:200px;
    background: #595959;
    color:#f8f8f8;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
#archiveSpace, #tagSpace, #artList {
    background:#d6d6d6;
    margin:0 5px;
    padding: 3px 2px;
    max-height:150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#artList {
    overflow-y:auto;
    max-height: none;
    clear:both;
}
#artList a:hover, #artList a:active {
    background: #ffffff;
}
#archiveSpace a, #tagSpace a {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color: #363636;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    margin: 3px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    height:18px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#archiveSpace a:hover, #archiveSpace a:active, #tagSpace a:hover, #tagSpace a:active {
    background:#ffffff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Here is my complete project on the GitHub for fuller refference:
https://github.com/DavidSili/MySITE
The files cited here are views/blog.php and css/style.css

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use 'Calculated height', so you can give your child  height: calc(100% - 150px); or you can try flexbox solution and give your parent div #articlebar {display: flex; flex-direction: column;} and #artList { flex-grow: 1; }

Comment: @AleksandarMilicevic "Calculated height" wouldn't work because the top is not fixed. And I just provided a flexbox example below.

Comment: Thanks guys, the flex thing really did the trick. calc would not do since the top is variable.
I was seeing "flex" word popping up in possible properties, but never bothered to check it up. Turns out this can solve tons of problems and make front-end job much more apealing (and less time consuming).
Once again thanks for a quick a thorough reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). This allows for a very versatile layout, and is new but [widelyy supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

It requires a combination of `flex-shrink` (everything you want to "shrink" to its calculated height) for the top two divs and the headers with `flex-grow` for the last one (everything you want to "grow" or expand to fill the space).

See the example below for a full working example.

```css
/* flex-box specific properties */
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#child1, #child2 {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
#child3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

/* other properties to make this snippet look good */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body, #parent {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#parent {
  background-color: grey;
}
#parent > div {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 10px;
}
#child1, #child2 {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1">Resize this</div>
  <div id="child2">Resize this</div>
  <div id="child3">This will take up rest of space</div>
</div>
```